# Strictly positive absolute maximum of a continuous function vanishing at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, maxima-minima

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous and not identically zero function such that $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x)=0.$$

Under which other extra assumptions I can say that $f$ has an absolute maximum which is strictly positive?
I mean that there exists $\bar{x}\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(\bar{x})\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f(\bar{x})>0$.

I am pretty convinced that assuming $f$ nonnegative, I can get the result. Anyone could please tell me if the existence of a strictly positive absolute maximum can be deduced assuming any other (possibly "lighter") assumption?

Comment: what's an absolute maximum?

Comment: If $f$ is strictly positive at one point, then the conclusion holds (and conversely).

Comment: @geetha290krm, could you please provide a bit more of details?

Comment: If $f(a)>0$ then there exists $T$ such that $f(x)<f(a)$ for $|x| >T$; $f$ has  a maximum in $[-T,T]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks! is $f(a)$ the desired maximum in $[-T, T]$?

Comment: Every continuous function on$[-T,T]$ attains its maximum at some point. That point need not be $a$.

Comment: But how can you prove that the maximum you find in $[-T, T]$ is strictly positive?

Comment: For arbitrary $T$ the maximum may be zero. But as $T \to \infty$, eventually you'll have $a \in [-T, T]$, at which point the function attains its maximum at a point $b$ for which $f(b) \geq f(a) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> If there exists a point $x$ such that $f(x)>0$

This is both necessary and sufficient. the necessity is obvious so let's prove the sufficiency:
To prove it you could take S to be the set of all such $f(x)$ and then prove $sup(S) \in S$, which is the same thing as saying $f$ has a positive maximum:

If $\sup(S)$ is in S then we are done.
If not, $\sup(S)$ is a limit point of $S$, so you can construct a sequence in $S$ that converges to $sup(S)$:

$\lim_{i \to \infty}f(x_i) = \sup(S)$

Now take the sequence of their inputs:

$x_1, x_2 ,\dots$

If it converges to $\alpha$ then $sup(S) = f(\alpha)$ (because $f$ is continuous) and we are done.

If it diverges you have 2 cases:

$1.$It diverges to infinity, which means $sup(S) = 0$ (because of the assumption: $f(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity) which is not possible, because all member of S are greater than zero.

$2.$it diverges but is bounded, so you have a subsequence that converges(Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem):

$\lim_{i \to \infty}u_i = U$

this would mean(Because $f$ is continuous):

$\lim_{i \to \infty}f(u_i) = f(U)$

So since the sequence:

$f(x_1),f(x_2),...$

Is convergent to $f(S)$ and since any subsequence must converge to the same limit, we have $sup(S) = f(U) \in S$ ($sup(S)>0$)